# Bitnami SonarQube VM on Azure: sonarqube could not be started

Tags: azure, sonarqube, bitnami

I installed the Bitnami SonarQube Virtual Machine from the Azure Marketplace. Everything seemed to work so far until I logged in and tried to install a plugin. At this point, SonarQube crashed.

Now, SonarQube refuses to start: `/opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/scripts/ctl.sh : sonarqube could not be started`

netstat shows that MySQL and Apache are up and running. All logs stopped working too. So, if I restart the VM or issue the command above, nothing new will be added to the log files.

I tried to remove all plugins from the filesystem and from the database but it didn't solve the problem.

I also tried to use a new database, but it stays blank.

Changing the log level to DEBUG didn't help either.

Reinstalling the VM from Azure obviously solves the problem until you interact with the SonarQube GUI again at which point it crashes again.

I have SonarQube working in a docker machine on a dev server too, where it has just 2GB of RAM and a rather slow processor. So I don't think it is a memory problem.

What should I try next?

Comment: Hey Paul, just checking if you have edited the sonar configs to run as in the context of sonar user or not?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm currently testing https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/sonarqube-azuresql. If updating to a current version of SonarQube works, I'll probably stick with it. If you try that one too: Note that you should install Java 8 instead of Java 10 as described.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Did you install the plugin using the admin dashboard or did you download the plugin using the command line and restarted the application? Please note that if you followed the latter case you also need to modify the permissions of the file to be owned by `sonarqube:sonarqube`. You have more information about how to install a plugin in the Bitnami solution [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/apps/sonarqube/#how-to-install-a-plugin-for-sonarqube)

Comment: @JotaMartos I installed it via the admin dashboard. But when completely removing and reinstalling the VM on Azure, it would crash again and not start, even without the plugin. So I think it does not relate to the specific plugin used. I started using the Azure template mentioned above and am quite happy with it. It ships with an old version of SonarQube but updating worked with no problems.